# Can we use a pronoun in the place of Attributive adjective?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, usage

Predicate adjectives Example: The sea is blue.
Attributive adjectives Example: The blue sea.

Attributive adjectives are adjectives that describe a characteristic (or attribute) of the noun or pronoun that they modify.

Here is my doubt.
Predicate adjectives Example: It is blue. 
Attributive adjectives Example: The blue ( ? ).

By definition, can we use "it" in (?) place or can we use a pronoun in the place of Attributive adjective?

Answer (score 1):

Pronouns are not usually modified because they're normally used anaphorically to substitute for the entire noun phrase.

> - He killed the blue person
> - He killed **him (=the blue person)**?

CGEL also says that pronouns do not normally take pre-head dependents.

> Pronouns do not normally allow internal pre-head dependents:**Extravagant he bought a new car; *I met interesting them all.*
>
> (430)

So your example *the blue it* is not idiomatic.

Pronouns can, however, take an adverb as a peripheral modifier:

> I love ***only*** you.

Or adjectival modifiers in some idiomatic phrases:

> *Poor you!*